# React App is giving error when using context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am learning React and right now trying to implement the old way of working with Context API but when I try to compile I get an error.

It says :

`TypeError: context is undefined. Version is 17.0.1`

Here are the files I use:

**Test0.js**

```
import React from 'react';
const Test0 = React.createContext();
export default Test0;
```

**Test1.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Test0 from './Test0';

class Test1 extends Component{
render(){
    return (
            <Test0.Consumer>
                {context => (<p>This is {context.name}</p> )}
            </Test0.Consumer>
        );
}
}
export default Test1;
```

**Test2.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Test0 from './Test0';
import Test1 from './Test1';

class Test2 extends Component{
state = {
    name: 'James',
    age : 30
}
render(){
    return (
        <Test0.Provider
            value={{
                name : this.state.name,
                age: this.state.age
            }}
        >
            <Test1 />
        </Test0.Provider>
        );
}
}

export default Test2;
```

I then render `<Test1 />` in **app.js**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I then render < Test1 /> in app.js

You need to render `Test2` because you define your Context Provider there. Below is the link for the full working code.

**CODESANDBOX LINK:** https://codesandbox.io/s/context-api-issue-lqkv8

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Test1` component which *consumes* `Test0`, a context, that you suppose to provide values, but in `Test0` you're providing no value. You wrongly implemented the provider in separate *Component*, `Test2`, that you don't render so `Test0` doesn't know about the provided values and it's assuming you didn't define the context.